# C Get All file names without extension from directory

Tags: c

Im looking for a way to read ALL txt files in a directory path without their extensions in C programming.

My code so far:

```
DIR *dr = opendir("Adding Customer");
struct dirent *de;  // Pointer for directory entry

// opendir() returns a pointer of DIR type. 


// for readdir()
while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", de->d_name);

closedir(dr);   


printf("===================================================\n\n");

printf("Press Any key to go back");
getch();
mainmenu();
```

Comment: Parse each `de->d_name` to find the delimiter that separates filename from extension.   Then print the part of `de->d_name` that precedes that delimiter.

Comment: Please don't misuse the "code snippet" feature for C code, it won't do anything good -> I removed it for you.

Comment: @Peter How do i do that?

Comment: If a platform-dependent solution is acceptable, you can use [`glob()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) on linux and other POSIX systems and [`FindFirstFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`FindNextFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) on windows.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I'm lost

Comment: Use `strrchr` to find the last `.` in the filename and then `stricmp` and truncate the filename.

Comment: @WeatherVane could you write a sample please

Comment: Have a go first, please. `strrchr` scans a string for the last occurrence of a character.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  `stricmp()` isn't C, nor POSIX (anymore?). POSIX has [`strcasecmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html)

Comment: For completeness the docs to [`strrchr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strrchr.html).

Comment: @alk I guess it would not be necessary to test the file extension if text files were filtered.